# Plot a graph for each country in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has three columns. The first one represents the country the second one is number of days and the third one is a count column. A sample would look like this:

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','USA','IND','UK','UK','UK'],
                   'Days':[4,5,6,8,9,4],
                   'Count':   [10,13,7,8,2,10]})`

I want to plot the Days on the X-axis and the Count on the Y-axis for each country (a line plot) but i want the graphs to be in one frame much like the pair plot. Is there a way to achieve this ? Also I am not sure how to filter the dataframe and plot the filtered object as i want one graph per country?

I want something along this line where for America it would look like this

`Days = [4,5]` 
`Count = [10,13]` 
`plt.plot(Days, Count, color='green')` 
`plt.xlabel('Days')`
`plt.ylabel('Count')` 
`plt.title('Days vs count for USA')`
`plt.show()`

But i want it for every country in a seperate plot but in one frame like a pair-plot.
Any help would be useful.Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for exactly; are you looking to make a scatter plot with points labeled by country?

Comment: @CollinPhillips : Sorry for the confusion. I want something along this line where Days = [4,5]
Count = [10,13]
plt.plot(Days, Count, color='green')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Days vs count for USA')
plt.show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better built in methods for this, but I would use:

```
for country in df['Country'].unique():
     df[df['Country']==country].sort_values('Days').plot.line(x='Days',
                                                              y='Count',
                                                              title=country)
```

Comment: P.S. It is not possible to make a useful line plot with only one observation (like 'IND') I'm assuming that's just an example.

Comment: Yes its just an example ... thank you ... let me try and see i hope this will help!